# How to limit the number of occurences of a unique id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I have 3 tables: manufacturer, products and clients
I have a query that gets me all the manufacturers with their products and their clients. I did this with two LEFT JOINS.

The result is more then 500 rows for 10 manufacturers because for every entry in the products and clients table, their is a row in the result with the id of the manufacturer.

I want to create a query that: gives me manufacturers with their products and their clients but not all the manufacturers, just 10 or 20 or a limited number.

How can I do this? 
I was thinking about this..

```
SELECT * 
FROM manufacturer as m
LEFT JOIN product as p ON ( m.mn_id = p.man_mn_id )
LEFT JOIN client  as c ON ( m.mn_id = c.man_mn_id )
WHERE m.mn_id IN ( SELECT mn_id
                   FROM manufacturer
                   WHERE mn_id >= ( SELECT FLOOR( MAX(mn_id) * RAND() )
                                    FROM manufacturer
                                  )
                   ORDER BY mn_id
                   LIMIT 10
                 )
```

Or is their a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by limiting manufactures,it will get 10 manufactures and will join these manufactures to their products and clients

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    manufacturer 
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 10) AS m  /* you can change limit to 20 or something you want */
  LEFT JOIN product AS p 
    ON (m.mn_id = p.man_mn_id) 
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS c 
    ON (m.mn_id = c.man_mn_id)
```

Comment: Tanks! That is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify your query to something like this, keeping the "random" feature you've got in your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM manufacturer ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as m
LEFT JOIN product as p ON (m.mn_id = p.man_mn_id)
LEFT JOIN client as c ON (m.mn_id = c.man_mn_id)
ORDER BY mn_id
```